# Run Java file(.class) in Linux with php exec(), return empty array

Tags: java, php, linux, exec

I can run java file using command line:

`java HelloWorld`

Now I am trying to run a HelloWorld.class file in php script using exec(). The problem is, when I run commands like:

`<?php exec("which java", $output);
       print_r($output); ?>`

it print correct result, but when I tried to run java file:

`<?php exec("java HelloWorld", $output);
       print_r($output); ?>`

it only print out `Array()`.

The content of HelloWorld.java is:

```
public class HelloWorld{

public static void main(String []args){
    System.out.println("Hello World!!!!");
 }
}
```

And I have already create the HelloWorld.class file using command line `javac HelloWorld`.

So how can I fix it?

PS. I changed the command into:

```
<?php exec("java HelloWorld 2>&1", $output);
   print_r($output); ?>
```

and I got `Array ( [0] => Error: Could not find or load main class HelloWorld )`

Does anyone know what the problem is?

Ok, I've fixed it.

I forget to set classpath when I use php exec().

So, the code should be:

```
<?php exec("java -cp '/var/www/html/run' HelloWorld 2>&1", $output);
      print_r($output);?>
```

Comment: Do you want the php to execute the java program and print out `Hello World!!!!` or just to print out `java HelloWorld`

Comment: print out Hello World!!!

Comment: Try executing `javac HelloWorld` and then `java HelloWorld` so that the program you wrote compiles first

Comment: Yes, I've done this step. I have HelloWorld.java and I've already create a HelloWorld.class file using command line "javac HelloWorld". Do, you mean I should add exec("javac HelloWorld"); in php file even when I've already have .class file?

Comment: No, I guess not if you already have a compiled version of the program, as long as the .class file is up to date.

Comment: Yes, the .class file is up to date.

Comment: Ok, I've fixed it.I forget to set classpath when I use php exec().
So, the code should be:<?php exec("java -cp '/var/www/html/run' HelloWorld 2>&1", $output);print_r($output);?>

Comment: Great! You should probably either close the question or answer it yourself now.